# responder chain issue of UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiresponder

I find that if a UIViewController is not in the hierarchy of the root view controller, it won't be in the responder chain from its view ->view controller ->super view....
I find such issue by debugging from a view with its nextResponder method.
It will skip the view controller in the chain if it's not added as a child view controller of a view controller in the hierarchy of the root view controller.

If its the rule that a view controller can be in the responder chain when it can be found from the root view controller's child view controller?

Comment: After more investigation, I find that when the uiviewcontroller is not the nextResponder, its view's _viewDelegate variable is nil. I think cocoa touch use the variable to determine whether the view's nextresponder is a viewcontroller or not. But when a uiviewcontroller's view has a nil _viewDelegate?

Comment: I find the root case is that the view controller is not retained and it's released. As the _viewDelegate seems to be a weak variable. Its value is set to nil after the view controller is released